# Easy: Why am I getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" ? (see line 24 in code)

Tags: python, html, regex, selenium

I know I'm doing something stupid but I can't figure it out. Can someone smarter than me please tell me what's wrong? Thank you. This script is supposed to open a URL, get the HTML, apply regex to get the content of interest, and then store the content in a file and repeat.

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re, csv, string, logging, codecs

class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.baseurl.com")
        self.selenium.start()
        self.selenium.set_timeout("60000")

    def test_untitled(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        spamReader = csv.reader(open('urlExtentions.csv', 'rb'))
        for row in spamReader:
            try:
                sel.open(row[0])
            except Exception, e:
                ofile = open('outputTest.csv', 'ab')
                ofile.write("error on %s: %s" % (row[0],e))
            else:
                time.sleep(5)
                htmlSource = sel.get_html_source()
                htmlSource2 = htmlSource.encode('utf-8')

    ##Next line throws "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

                bodyText = re.DOTALL('<h3>.*?<footer>', htmlSource2)

                ofile = open('output.txt', 'ab')
                ofile.write(bodyText.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
            ofile.close()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

Comment: Rather than inject a comment, can you please also give us the full traceback of the exception? That would give us *far more* context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) is a constant in the `re` module. It is not a function and you cannot call it. It is meant to be used as a flag in `flags` arguments to `re` module functions.

If you wanted to do a search for the regular expression, use:

```
bodyText = re.search('<h3>.*?<footer>', htmlSource2, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

`re.search()` returns a `MatchObject` so you probably want to get the matched text:

```
bodyText = bodyText.group()
```

Note that you already encoded your HTML to UTF-8:

```
htmlSource2 = htmlSource.encode('utf-8')
```

so you don't want to do this *again*:

```
ofile.write(bodyText.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Remove the `.encode()` call there.

Note that rather than use regular expressions, you really should use a proper HTML parser here. BeautifulSoup would be an excellent choice, for example.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test2.py", line 26, in test_untitled
    ofile.write(bodyText.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 7449: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Only change, from "bodyText = re.DOTALL('<h3>.*?<footer>', htmlSource2)" to "bodyText = re.search('<h3>.*?<footer>', htmlSource2, flags=re.DOTALL).group()" ?

Comment: @KenBurnsFan1: You are trying to encode *a byte string*. It is already encoded. Python tries to first decode so it has a `unicode` object to encode. You don't need to encode what is already encoded.

Comment: @KenBurnsFan1: You already encoded the data earlier in the method.